# Determining if the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty {1\over {n\ln(n)\ln(\ln(n))}}$ is convergent or divergent and justifying the answer.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

By far, these infinite series and sequences have been my biggest problem in calculus 2, and this problem really puts my limited knowledge to the test.

I have found that posting these pictures helps show everyone what I have learned so far, and then I'll try to solve it myself.

Chapter and section names:

[image]

Rules that my book gives me to solve these problems. This shows more of what I should and do know:

[image]

Looking at those rules, it doesn't really even seem to help me with this problem. The only way I could see this being solved with what I know is with the integral test.

Also, note that it starts at 2 (I almost missed that myself).

If I'm going to try to use the integral test, then here is my book's definition of it:

[image]

And here is the question again: Determining if the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty {1\over {nln(n)ln(ln(n))}}$ is convergent or divergent and justifying the answer. I honestly don't know where to start with this one, I would try but there are a lot of changes from previous questions, and it makes it a lot harder.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the integral of $\frac{1}{n\ln n\ln (\ln n) }$?

Comment: Cauchy condensation test.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I have not learned about that yet.

Comment: how about let $x=ln(n)$?

Comment: @kingW3 I came up with $ln(\left\lvert {ln(ln(x))} \right\lvert) + C$

Comment: so do you see that it diverges?

Comment: @valer I do not see that yet. What method did you use? The integral test?

Comment: @DevHeavy Then learn it today. What are you waiting for? Calculus 27?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I would if I had more time and if it pertained to what I'm doing, but this is an obscure homework problem from my book that does not have a solution or a hint about what to use. However, I do know that it should be able to be solved with the stuff I posted in my question above. I'll just have to keep working on it. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Okay when x goes to infinity so does $ln(x)$ then since $ln(x)=t$ goes to infinity then so does $ln(t) =ln(ln(x)) $, also $k=ln(t) $ goes to infinity then so does $ln(k) =ln(ln(ln(x)))$ so by integral comparison it diverges.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Cauchy condensation test, look at $\sum 2^n a_{2^n}$. This gives 
$$\sum \frac{1}{n\ln n}$$ and applying it a second time we get 
$$\sum \frac{1}{n}$$ which diverges, thus the above two series also diverge.

Comment: I have not learned about this test yet. But if I were to use the integral test do you think it would work? I'm having trouble making sure it fits the parameters that my book gives me (I posted my book's definition above).

Comment: Its too hard to integrate.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, thank you for trying to help. I'll have to ask for help outside of StackExchange.